# Koa web application randomly loading routes and randomly presenting "not found" on screen

Tags: node.js, mongodb, routes, koa, nunjucks

I'm using Koa with Koa-Nunjucks 2 for templating and mongodb as the database to create a simple blog. I have set up routes and for some reason when I test the site on my localhost it will load the page some of the times and the other times it will display "not found". I will go through different routes and randomly if you go back and try again it will display the page or if you refresh the page a bunch it will finally display. This is the index.js file. All routes will randomly break there is no specific one.

```
//////////////////////////
//Initializing Environment Variables
//npm i dotenv
//npm i koa-methodoverride
//npm i koa-bodyparser
//////////////////////////
require('dotenv').config();
const override = require('koa-methodoverride');
const parser = require('koa-bodyparser');

//////////////////////////
//Connecting the DB
//npm i mongoose
//////////////////////////
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const db = mongoose.connection;
const host = process.env.host;
const dbupdate = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true};
mongoose.connect(host, dbupdate);

mongoose.connection.on

db.on('error', (err) => console.log('Error, DB Not connected'));
db.on('connected', () => console.log ('connected to mongo'));
db.on('disconnected', () => console.log ('Mongo is disconnected'));
db.on('open', () => console.log ('Connection Made!'));

//////////////////////////
//Model Schema
//////////////////////////
const Recipe = require('./model/recipe.js');


//////////////////////////
//Create Our Server Object
//////////////////////////
const koa = require('koa');
const server = new koa();

//////////////////////////
//Create Our Static Folder
//npm i koa-static
//////////////////////////
const static = require('koa-static');

//////////////////////////
//Creating Our Router
//npm i koa-router
//////////////////////////
const Router = require('koa-router');
const route = Router();

//////////////////////////
//Initializing views
//npm i koa-views
//npm i nunjucks
//////////////////////////
// const views = require('koa-views');
// const nunj = require('nunjucks');
// nunj.configure('./views', {autoescape: true});
const koaNunjucks = require('koa-nunjucks-2');
const path = require('path');

//////////////////////////
//Routes
//Route.get - route.post - route.patch - post.put - route.delete
//////////////////////////
route.get('/', async (ctx, next) => {
    console.log('connected to root route');
    return Recipe.find({}, async (error, results) => {
        console.log(results);
        await ctx.render('index', {
            posts: results,
            name: process.env.NAME
        });
        
    }).clone()
});

route.get('/view/:id', async (ctx, next) => {
    console.log('connected to recipe route');
    return Recipe.findById(ctx.params.id, async (error, results) => {
        console.log(results)
        await ctx.render('recipe', {
            post: results
        });
    }).clone()
});

route.post('/admin', async (ctx, next) => {
    return Recipe.find({}, async (error, results) => {
        console.log(ctx.request.body)
        console.log(process.env.pw)
        if(ctx.request.body.pw === process.env.pw)
        {
            console.log('Connected to Admin Route');
            return await ctx.render('admin', {
                posts: results
            });
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('Connected to Index Route');
            await ctx.redirect('/');
        }
    }).clone()
});

// route.get('/', (ctx, next) => {
//     return ctx.render('index.html', {
//         name: process.env.NAME
//     })
// });

// route.get('/:name', (ctx, next) => {
//     return ctx.render('./index.html', {
//         name: ctx.params.name
//     })
// });

//////////////////////////
//Middleware
//////////////////////////
// server.use(views('./views', {map: {html: 'nunjucks'}}));
server.use(override('_method'));
server.use(parser());
server.use(koaNunjucks({
    ext: 'njk',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'views'),
    nunjucksConfig: {
        trimBlocks: true
    }
}));
server.use(route.routes());
server.use(static('./public'));





//////////////////////////
//Our Listener on Port 1985
//////////////////////////
server.listen(1985);
```

When I didn't have async and awaits the info would only load once and then if you tried refreshing the page it wouldn't load again. My grasp of how async and await works is very basic. It all seems very random and I'm not sure what's causing it to not consistently show the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should add `await` before each `Recipe.find`. The `find`-method looks like as synchronous (since it has a callback) and therefore you should wait till it will be done.

```
const res = await Recipe.find({}, async (error, results) => {... })
return res.clone()
```

P.S. I don't know `koa`.